# gcc arm -- ensuring args are retained when inlining functions with inline asm statements

Tags: gcc, arm, inline

I have a series of functions that are ultimately implemented with an SVC call. For instance:

```
void func(int arg) {
    asm volatile ("svc #123");
}
```

as you might imagine, the SVC operates on 'arg' which is presumably in a register.  if i explictly add a 'noinline' attribute to the definition, everything works as you'd expect.

but, were the function inlined at a higher optimization level, the code that loads 'arg' into a register would be omitted -- as there is apprently no reference to 'arg'.

I've tried adding a 'used' attribute to the declaration of 'arg' itself -- but gcc apparently yields a warning in this case.

I've also tried adding "dummy" asm statements such as

```
asm ("" : "=r"(arg));
```

But this didn't appear to work in general. (maybe i need to say volatile here as well???)

Anyway, it seems unfortunate to have an explicit function call for a routine whose body essentially consists of one asm statement.

Answer (score 4):

A relevant recipe is in the GCC manual, in [Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) section, that uses `sysint` with the same role of your `svc` instruction. The idea is to define a local register variable with a specified register, and then use extended `asm`syntax to add inputs and outputs to the inline assembly block.

I tried to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

__attribute__((always_inline))
uint32_t func(uint32_t arg) {
    register uint32_t r0 asm("r0") = arg;
    register uint32_t result asm("r0");
    asm volatile ("svc #123":"=r" (result) : "0" (r0));
    return result;
}

uint32_t foo(void) {
    return func(2);
}
```

This is the disassembly of the compiled (with -O2 flag) object file:

```
00000000 <func>:
   0:   ef00007b        svc     0x0000007b
   4:   e12fff1e        bx      lr

00000008 <foo>:
   8:   e3a00002        mov     r0, #2
   c:   ef00007b        svc     0x0000007b
  10:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

`func` is expanded inline and the argument is put in `r0` correctly. I believe `volatile` is necessary, because if you don't make use of the return value of the service call, then the compiler might assume that the assembly piece of code is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a single asm block, compiler is still free to treat two asm blocks individually until otherwise specified. Meaning requirements put on second asm block won't have any effect on the first one.

You are assuming registers will be in their right places because of the calling convention.

What about something like this? (didn't test)

```
void func(int arg) {
    asm volatile (
        "mov r0, %[code]\n\t"
        "svc #123"
        :
        : [code]"r" (code)
    );
}
```

For more information, see [ARM GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html).